# Refer to numbered item in Google Document

Tags: google-docs

Is there a way to refer (dynamically) to a numbered item in a Google Doc?

For example, say I have a list:

1. Item one
2. Item two
3. Item three

and I wish to refer to item 2. in a normal paragraph, but in such a way that if I were to insert an item above item two, like this:

1. Item one
2. Inserted item
3. Item two
4. Item three

then my reference to item 2. in my paragraph should update to 3, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Comunity User 13 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Smart References" Add-On for Google Docs to insert references to numbered list items, and to synchronise all the references in a document when list item numbers change.

*Full disclosure: I am the author of the Smart Refereces Add-On*

See: https://sealionsoftware.com/smart-references/